# navigation drawer with min-sdk 10 android

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application that will support min sdk 10. When I test it with android 2.3 the application crushed due to navigation drawer and action bar. How to make it work with min sdk 10?

Comment: are you using AppCompat ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the compatibility library offered by google.
Follow this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: no i'm not using Appcompat i just define my own style and color